# new DateTime() vs new DateTime('NOW') in php

Tags: php, datetime

Before I post this question, I searched in several places for answer for this. I really could not find the proper answer.

I evaluated the both way following...

```
$date = new DateTime()
```

amd

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW')
```

Is it must for the both above give the same result or is there any circumstance they both differ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'll look into `DateTime` [constructor definition](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) you'll see that `now` is default value for initializing string:

```
public DateTime::__construct() ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

That means both two calls above are always equal. If you'll not specify anything as initializing string, PHP will substitute `now` implicitly for you.

Comment: can you also answer why 'now' and 'today' are not equal?

Comment: @temirbek Not tested, but I assume that "now" is current day _and_ time, while "today" is current date with time set to zero.